# Is it possible to view a webpage running locally on your computer on an android over USB?

Tags: android

I have set up a webpage locally on my computer, I wish to run it on my android-phone without pushing it to a server every time. Can I somehow access the site directly from the computer?

(I have the remote debugging up and running)

Comment: Can't you connect to your PC directly via its local IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes u can access it easily if you are on the same lan using a common wifi router...

suppose your computer ip is 192.168.0.10 then you just need to enter that address in the browser and its done...

If you install wamp or lamp or xamp using `http://localhost` we can access the site if you are on wifi then enter `http://192.168.0.10`  (supposing your PC address is 192.168.0.10) and you will see the website...

There can be a case where we need to port forward on router for http connections if it does not run...

thx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just create a simple Webserver on your Computer (xmpp is working fine or a simple apache). Then you may want to access it by using your Computers IP when it's connected to the same network.

This may be the simplest case. You can also use a simple batch file (build script) which use adb push the html to your device anytime before you run it.

Comment: Would MAMP suffice for this?

Comment: Use Apachefriends XMPP since it's available as Portable and it's quick installed. https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html

Anyway, you should prefer using ADB push if its only one static page